# C++ macro '##' doesn't work after '->' operator

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a shared_ptr object x, which has get and set methods as follows:

```
x->a_value();
x->set_a_value();
x->b_value();
x->set_b_value();
```

When i try to define a macro:

```
#define MAC(type) \
  x->set_##type##_value(val);

MAC(a)
```

It works fine, but when I do:

```
#define MAC(type) \
  x->##type##_value();

MAC(a)
```

it gives the following compile error:
`pasting formed '->a', an invalid preprocessing token`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The preprocessor works on "tokens" - likes names and operators.

The `##` operator creates a new token by pasting smaller parts together. In the first example `set_##type##_value` becomes `set_a_value`, which is a valid token.

In the second example `->##type##_value` would become `->a_value`, which is *not* a valid preprocessor token. It ought to be two tokens.

If you just make the line `x->type##_value();` it should work. You get the separate tokens `x`, `->`, `a_value`, `(`, `)`, and `;`.

Comment: Is any particular useful purpose served by the requirement that a token be formed that bridges the ##, as opposed to merely allowing the contents to either side to merge into a token if appropriate?  The only advantage I can see to having the preprocessor treat 1.2E+5 and 0x1E+4 as one token instead of three is that it's possible to concatenate pieces to form a floating-point number, but in the absence of that constraint on `##` it wouldn't matter.

Comment: These rules goes way back to the C language standardization and I don't know how they figured out that this was the way it worked (or should work). Debugging macros is already hard, and having the `##` operator sometimes silently fail to paste tokens wouldn't make that any easier. For example in `#if x == y` it is important to be strict about how `x` and `y` are formed.

Comment: The behavior of `#if` is weird in a lot of ways; a compile-time conditional directive that was evaluated at a later translation stage would help avoid much of the weirdness.  I don't see where having something like `#define JOIN(x,y) x##y` squawk unless the rightmost token of x and leftmost token of y interact helps anything, though.  What sorts of `x` and `y` did you have in mind for your `#if`?

Comment: The people to ask are not the people who came up with the C standard, but implementors. The C standard leaves the behaviour of `##` where the result would not form a token undefined, so implementations are already allowed to silently accept `##` in all cases. That said, it's unclear what in that case the result of concatenating `a` and `0.1` should be. An error? A single `a0.1` token (which does not exist in standard C)? The unconcatenated `a` and `0.1` tokens? Re-tokenised `a0` and `.1` tokens? I suspect that there is no benefit in requiring any particular behaviour.

Answer (score 17):

What it says on the tin: `->a` is not a single, valid preprocessor token: it's two tokens. You do not need to paste here.

```
#define MAC(type) \
  x->type##_value();
```

Comment: Quentin, how are you using "tin" in your answer? I can't decide if that's a typo for something or a new usage for that word I've never seen.

Comment: "does exactly what it says on the tin" was originally a marketing slogan in the UK (for varnish / paint products). In this case, it just means "the problem is what the error message says".

Comment: @Segfault See [Exactly What It Says on the Tin](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExactlyWhatItSaysOnTheTin). Thank me later.

Comment: @MaskedMan please put a warning before liking to tvtropes some people intent to work today :)

Answer (score 1):

The token-pasting operator (`##`) is used to concatenate two tokens into a single **valid** token.

When you write

```
x->##type##_value();
```

- The first processed token is `x`.
- The next token is formed by concatenating the token `->` with `type`, since `type` is `a`, the result of the concatenation is `->a`, which ought to be a valid token, but is not.

Hence, you get the error: `pasting formed '->a', an invalid preprocessing token`.

To fix this, just write

```
x->type##_value();
```

This way

- The first token parsed is `x`.
- The next token parsed is `->`.
- The next token is formed by concatenating the token `type` (which becomes `a`) with the token `_value`. This gives `a_value`, which is a valid token.
- The next token is `(`.
- The next token is `)`.
- The last token is `;`.